# How to detect collisions in AS3?

Tags: collision-detection, actionscript-3, box2d

I'm trying to make a simple game, when the ball falls into certain block, you win.

**Mechanics:** The ball falls through several obstacles, in the end there are two blocks, if the ball touches the left block you win, the next level will contain more blocks and less space between them.

**Test the movie** (click on the screen to drop the ball):
http://gabrielmeono.com/downloads/Lucky_Hit_Alpha.swf

**These are the main variables:**

```
    var winBox:QuickObject;//You win
    var looseBox:QuickObject;//You loose
    var gameBall:QuickObject;//Ball dropped
```

**Question:**

*How do I trigger a collision function if the ball hits the winBox? (Win message/Next level)*

Thanks, here is the full code:

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width = 600, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

    public class LuckyHit extends MovieClip {

        public var sim:QuickBox2D;
        var winBox:QuickObject;
        var looseBox:QuickObject;
        var gameBall:QuickObject;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function LuckyHit()
        {
            sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
            //sim.createStageWalls();
            winBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});
            looseBox = sim.addBox({x:15,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});


            // make obstacles
            for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/50); i++){ 
            //End
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

            //Mid End

                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});


            //Middle Start
                 sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:09, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:08, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:07, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:06, radius:0.1, density:0});

            }

            sim.start();


            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        }

        /**
         * ..
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */

        private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(1), radius:0.25, density:5});


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got help from atomparker at stackexchange, The class needed is QuickContacts inside BOX2D library.

Here's the code for future reference:

```
   var simContacts:QuickContacts;

public function LuckyHit()
{
    ...
    simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
    simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
}

...

private function contactListener(event:Event)
{
    if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox, gameBall))
    {
        // They won.
    }
}
```

The relevant class in the [QuickBox2D documentation](http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/docs/html/index.html) is **QuickContacts**.

Comment: maybe complex physics, you will need APE http://www.cove.org/ape/ and of course there are a bunch other libraries as well.